It is the faith of who or what in Hebrews 11:30?

By faith the walls of Jericho fell down, after they were compassed about seven days. - Hebrews 11:30

Everywhere else in this chapter the format followed is, "By the faith of so and so such and such happened".  But in this case we are told, "By faith the walls fell..."
I know this appears like a strange question as it seems obvious that it is the people of Israel's faith as in, "By faith they passed through the Red sea as by dry land".  However, that says "By faith they passed..."
The verse in question says "By faith the walls of Jericho fell ..."  Fell is active tense (not passive as I expected) meaning that the subject, the walls, performed the action.  In similar fashion, the wind and the waves actively obey the Lord Jesus in Matthew 8:27 and grow still.
Without ascribing consciousness to a wall, Is it possible that the faith, or certainty, or sureness of the walls of Jericho is in view as they actively fall in obedience?

If there is any ambiguity, it is between the faith of the ancient Israelites causing the walls to fall and the faith of the author of Hebrews in trusting that the story is true.  In the context of the preceding verses, it is clearly the former.

The verses surrounding this verse 30 show why sometimes the writer said "he" [had faith] or "they" [had faith]. But never does it say "it" had faith. As pointed out in the question, walls cannot have faith!
In verses 24 to 28, it is the individual, Moses, of whom it is said "he" had faith (to do various things.) Three times, Moses is said to have shown faith (refusing to be called the son of Pharaoh's daughter; forsaking Egypt; keeping the Passover.)
In verse 29 it is a collective group of people of whom it is said, "they" acted in faith (passing through the Red Sea to get to the other side.)
Then, in the verse in question, comes, "By faith the walls of Jericho fell down after they were compassed about seven days." No way could the word "it" fit into such a sentence! Something happened to walls, which cannot have faith. But it took faith for God's command to the Israelites and the priests to do what was needed, for seven consecutive days. And on the seventh day, they were to march around seven times instead of once, blowing trumpets. Can you imagine the reaction of all the inhabitants of Jericho, crowding the walls, to observe this strange tactic? Day one they might have been very nervous, but days two to six, they might have started jeering, laughing, and insulting the marchers. Increasingly so. Day seven might have seen them mock again, but as the marching continued again, and again, and again, and again and again, and again...with trumpets blasting... perhaps fear might have set in.
Whatever, it must have taken a great deal of faith for God's command to be carried out on seven consecutive days. It was the faith of those obedient ones that led to God causing the walls to come crashing down on day seven.
Then (back to chapter 11), verse 31 resumes identifying one individual (Rahab) as showing faith.
It seems that the walls of Jericho, mentioned at the start of the sentence, requires the sense that those walls were not what showed faith. Yes, the walls actively fell down, but the obedient marchers and trumpet-blowers were the ones whose faith, that persisted over seven days, is what the writer of Hebrews is praising - not for what they did, but for their faith.

This is a classic case of the Greek construction with an implied subject.  This is true in Heb 11:29 and 30.  Let me set this out more clearly with my own overly literal translation:

V29: By faith [they] passed through the Red Sea, as through dry land ...
V30: By faith the walls of Jericho fell [after the people] encircled for seven days

Note that the highlighted words in square brackets are implied but explicitly absent in both cases.  Those exercising faith on both cases are the people of Israel.

Active TenseItis true that the "active tense" is used. But the question's explanation blunders in assuming that it is "referring to faith." The walls did the falling (active tense), not the "faithing."
It was by the faith of Joshua and the people that this was accomplished---even though they are not specifically mentioned in this sentence. Concrete objects (like walls) are impossible to have abstract actions (have faith).
It was by the faith of the marching (obedient) people that the walls fell down. The "walls" are the subject of this sentence, and "fell" is the verb...but "By faith" is the prepositional phrase that describes the method or manner.
So there is no enigma here in comparison to other verses about "faith" of the people.
[Note: when the wind or a storm "obeys" a command of Jesus, this is simply the use of metaphorical language. It is not attributing personality to the physical objects! When a disease is commanded to leave a sick person by Jesus, it does not mean it has volitional capabilities. Here again, writers are simply using metaphorical---or anthropological---verbage.  It is the faith of Jesus (or healer) that is the energizing agent.]
